# Match an expression with no << or ]]

Tags: regex, angularjs-ng-pattern

I need to match the pattern only if `<<` or `>>` or `]]` or `[[` is not present in the string.

If any of these special characters are present the match should be zero else it should match.

For example, I have an expression `Stackoverflow` which should return as a match but if I have `Stack]]over<<flow` I should not get a trueful response. The following pattern unfortunately does not work:

```
/^(\[\[)|(\]\])|(\<\<)|(\>\>)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regular expression and negate the result:

```
<<|>>|\]\]|\[\[
```

Here is a live example:

```js
var regex = /<<|>>|\]\]|\[\[/;
var strings = [
  "Stackoverflow",
  "Stack]]over<<flow"
];

for(var i=0; i<strings.length; i++) {
  console.log(!regex.test(strings[i]));
}
```

---

If you can't negate the result (like when using Angular's `ng-pattern`), you can also use a negative lookahead:

```
^((?!<<|>>|\]\]|\[\[).)*$
```

Here is a live example:

```js
var regex = /^((?!<<|>>|\]\]|\[\[).)*$/;
var strings = [
  "Stackoverflow",
  "Stack]]over<<flow"
];

for(var i=0; i<strings.length; i++) {
  console.log(regex.test(strings[i]));
}
```

Comment: Hi I have to use this in ng-pattern of html input and cannot use in javascript or angular js.how to use negation in ng-pattern instead of using !regex ? Thank you for the quick solution

Comment: @user4895544 Okay, I've updated the answer.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you :)